# AWS - trying to install the kopf plugin for Elasticsearch on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have a `ubuntu` EC2 instance in AWS.

I already installed Java and Elasticsearch, and now i'm trying to install Kopf so i can manage my nodes using the web UI.

However, when i try to install it using:
`bin/elasticsearch-plugin install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf`

when i'm in the:
`/usr/share/elasticsearch` directory, i get the error:

> ERROR: Unknown plugin lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf

What am i doing wrong?
(my Elasticsearch version is 6.2.2)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf

> Kopf is no longer maintained. A replacement(cerebro) has been
>   developed and is currently maintained at
>   https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro. At this point, cerebro should be
>   pretty much feature equivalent of kopf, with a few new features on
>   top.